# Installing NumPy via Anaconda in Windows

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda

I am trying to use Numpy in a Python 2.7.8 script in Windows. So, I download and installed the latest version of Anaconda (I also want to use some of the other tools in Anaconda) to the directory "C:/Anaconda". As default, I checked the boxing asking me if I wanted to add the path to the binary files to the Windows PATH.

After checking PATH, it contains the following: "C:\Anaconda;C:\Anaconda\Scripts".

Then, after installation I open a new Command Prompt, and in the Python envirnoment, I enter "import numpy", but this gives the error: "ImportError: No module named numpy".

What stage have I missed out in the installation process?

***** EDIT *****

I have just noticed that there is no file called "numpy" in either "C:\Anaconda" or "C:\Anaconda\Scripts". But according to the Anaconda website (http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs.html), the installation should come with Numpy...

***** EDIT *****

It seems that Windows was running Python from an existing version of Python I had installed, which was not associated with NumPy. After deleting this, and running Python from the Anaconda installation, NumPy is now being recognised.

Comment: Is your Command Prompt a new one, opened after installing Anaconda?

Comment: Yes -- a new Command Prompt instance after installation is complete.

Answer (score 25):

I had the same problem, getting the message "ImportError: No module named numpy".

I'm also using anaconda and found out that I needed to add numpy to the ENV I was using. You can check the packages you have in your environment with the command:

> conda list

So, when I used that command, numpy was not displayed. If that is your case, you just have to add it, with the command:

> conda install numpy

After I did that, the error with the `import numpy` was gone

Comment: This helped me big time. Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: Thanks. Solved my issue!

Answer (score 6):

Yep you should start anaconda's python in order to use python libs which come with anaconda. Or otherwise you have to manually add `anaconda\lib` to `pythonpath` which is less trivial. You can start anaconda's python by a full path:

```
path\to\anaconda\python.exe
```

or you can run the following two commands as an admin in cmd to make windows pipe every `.py` file to anaconda's python:

```
assoc .py=Python.File
ftype Python.File=C:\path\to\Anaconda\python.exe "%1" %*
```

after this you'll be able just to call python scripts without specifying the python executable at all.

Answer (score 2):

Anaconda folder basically resides in C:\Users\\Anaconda. Try setting the PATH to this folder.

Answer (score 2):

Move `path\to\anaconda` in the PATH above `path\to\python`

Answer (score 1):

The above answers seem to resolve the issue.
If it doesn't, then you may also try to update conda using the following command.

```
conda update conda
```

And then try to install numpy using

```
conda install numpy
```