# ImportError: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat with python 2.7.12

Tags: python, python-2.7, visual-c++, distutils, python-c-extension

I'm quite new to python and I want to use the module "lic_internal" with python 2.7.12 on Windows 64bit but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "04_report.py", line 32, in <module>
import utils_show as ushow
  File "./libs\utils_show.py", line 45, in <module>
import lic_internal
  File "D:\Programme\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 445, in load_module language_level=self.language_level)
  File "D:\Programme\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 234, in load_module exec("raise exc, None, tb", {'exc': exc, 'tb': tb})
  File "D:\Programme\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 216, in load_module inplace=build_inplace, language_level=language_level)
  File "D:\Programme\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 192, in build_module reload_support=pyxargs.reload_support)
  File "D:\Programme\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyxbuild.py", line 102, in pyx_to_dll dist.run_commands()
  File "D:\Programme\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands self.run_command(cmd)
  File "D:\Programme\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command cmd_obj.run()
  File "D:\Programme\Python27\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\build_ext.py", line 164, in run _build_ext.build_ext.run(self)
  File "D:\Programme\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 339, in run self.build_extensions()
  File "D:\Programme\Python27\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\build_ext.py", line 172, in build_extension self.build_extension(ext)
  File "D:\Programme\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 498, in build_extension depends=ext.depends)
  File "D:\Programme\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 474, in compile self.initialize()
  File "D:\Programme\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 384, in initialize vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)
  File "D:\Programme\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 272, in query_vcvarsall raise DistutilsPlatformError("Unable to find vcvarsall.bat")

ImportError: Building module lic_internal failed: ['DistutilsPlatformError: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat\n']
```

I have installed "Visual C++ for Python 2.7" and tried to change the path in "Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py" as follows:

```
def query_vcvarsall(version, arch="x86"):
"""Launch vcvarsall.bat and read the settings from its environment
"""
vcvarsall = find_vcvarsall(version)
vcvarsall = "C:/Users/Christian/AppData/Local/Programs/Common/Microsoft/Visual C++ for Python/9.0" + "/vcvarsall.bat"
interesting = set(("include", "lib", "libpath", "path"))
```

Which means I saved in "vcvarsall" the exact path.

Then I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "04_report.py", line 32, in <module> import utils_show as ushow
File "./libs\utils_show.py", line 45, in <module> import lic_internal
File "D:\Programme\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 445, in load_module language_level=self.language_level)
File "D:\Programme\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 234, in load_module exec("raise exc, None, tb", {'exc': exc, 'tb': tb})
File "D:\Programme\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 216, in load_module inplace=build_inplace, language_level=language_level)
File "D:\Programme\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 192, in build_module reload_support=pyxargs.reload_support)
File "D:\Programme\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyxbuild.py", line 102, in pyx_to_dll dist.run_commands()
File "D:\Programme\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands self.run_command(cmd)
File "D:\Programme\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command cmd_obj.run()
File "D:\Programme\Python27\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\build_ext.py", line 164, in run _build_ext.build_ext.run(self)
File "D:\Programme\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 339, in run self.build_extensions()
File "D:\Programme\Python27\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\build_ext.py", line 172, in build_extensions self.build_extension(ext)
File "D:\Programme\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 498, in build_extension depends=ext.depends)
File "D:\Programme\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 549, in compile raise CompileError(msg)  

ImportError: Building module lic_internal failed: ["CompileError: command 'C:\\\\Users\\\\Christian\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\Programs\\\\Common\\\\Microsoft\\\\Visual C++ for Python\\\\9.0\\\\VC\\\\Bin\\\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2\n"]
```

Furthermore, I have Visual C++ 2013 installed on my computer but as I downloaded the C++ compiler package for python it shouldn't be necessary, right?

Answer (score -1):

If you still have the problem, I solved it by uninstalling other pythons in the system. For assurance you need to define the path of the python which you want to work with using https://stackoverflow.com/a/30272728/7497110 then open the msvc9compiler.py and do this https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/CythonExtensionsOnWindows. Then you might get the well known header problem (i.e. *.h No such file or directory). In such case you can use the instructions in http://www.pythonlibrary.org/notes/open_glcontext_notes.htm. Keep in mind to update the python especially the distutils and numpy. Please let me know if the problem is solved.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't add _Me too!_ as answers. It doesn't actually provide an answer to the question and can be perceived as noise by its future visitors. If you have a different but related question then [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) it (reference this one if it will help provide context). If you're interested in this specific question, you can [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) it or leave a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).