# installing Numpy by pyzo errors

Tags: python, numpy, conda, pyzo

excuse me but I just install Pyzo and follow the instructions from that website http://www.pyzo.org/start.html

I now get troubles to load the "numpy" module

when i enter `conda install numpy`

after a while it show me that:

#DATA CODES (start)

Fetching package metadata ...............
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

```
mkl:       2017.0.1-0   
numpy:     1.12.1-py36_0
```

The following packages will be SUPERCEDED by a higher-priority channel:

```
conda:     4.3.14-py36_1 --> 4.2.13-py36_0 conda-forge
conda-env: 2.6.0-0       --> 2.6.0-0       conda-forge
```

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

#DATA CODES (end)

and I reply y to the consol but the program end here and when I want to load numpy I get that:

#DATA CODES (start)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    from numpy import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

#DATA CODES (end)

could someone explain me how to instal numpy?

Comment: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26318995/installing-numpy-via-anaconda-in-windows