# Stuggling with Homework - Pandas, dependencies etc

Tags: python, pandas, dependencies, required

I have some code that someone helped me make, but they are unavailable and its not working, it is saying that there are "Missing required dependencies"

I've meddled with it

```
import pandas as pd
cereal_data = pd.read_csv("./cereal_data.csv")
cereal_data.head(10)
print(f'Total Number of Cereals Available:  
{cereal_data["Cereal"].nunique()}')
print(f'Total Number of Manufacturers Available:    
{cereal_data["Manufacturer"].nunique()}')
print(f'Total Number of Shelves Available:    
{cereal_data["Shelf"].nunique()}')
shelf_cereal_data = cereal_data.groupby('Shelf').Cereal.nunique()
shelf_cereal_data.plot(kind = "bar", title="Cereal Count per Shelf")
stats = shelf_cereal_data.tolist()
print(f'The Shelf ID of Shelf with Maximum Cereals:    
{stats.index(max(stats)) + 1}')
manufacturer_cereal_data =    
cereal_data.groupby('Manufacturer').Cereal.count()
cereal_perc =    
manufacturer_cereal_data.div(cereal_data["Cereal"].nunique()).mul(100)
cereal_perc.plot(kind='pie',autopct='%1.1f%%', title="Contribution per 
manufacturer")
cereal_data.groupby(['Manufacturer'])    
['Calories','Potassium'].mean().plot(kind='bar', figsize=(12,5),    
title="Average Calories and Potassium per Manufacturer")
```

Here is what it is saying: But 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/dwarf/OneDrive/Documents/project.py", line 2, in 
    if **name** == '**main**':
  File "C:\Users\dwarf\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas__init__.py", line 19, in

builtins.ImportError: Missing "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))required dependencies ['numpy']

Here is expected outcome:

3.7.1 (default, Dec 14 2018, 13:28:58) 
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)]
Python Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
[evaluate project.py]
========Dataset details========

Number of Cereals: 76
Number of Shelves: 3
Number of different manufacturers: 6

================================

Shelf 3 contains highest (36) amount of cereals.

================================

General Mills : 28.95%
Kellogs : 30.26%
Nabisco : 7.89%
Post : 11.84%
Quaker Oats : 10.53%
Ralstone Purina : 10.53%

Comment: You need to install the package `numpy`: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26318995/installing-numpy-via-anaconda-in-windows for more.

Comment: go to terminal and type 'pip install numpy'