# ValueError when trying to use pipenv install

Tags: python, valueerror, pipenv

I am totally new to this. So I installed pipenv using 'pip install pipenv'. I have python version 3.8.2, pip version 20.1.1 and pipenv version 2020.6.2 . 
But when I try to run 'pipenv install' it gives the following error.

```
    C:\Users\rd463>pipenv install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python382\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\python.py", line 618, in parse_executable
    result_version = get_python_version(path)
  File "D:\python382\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\utils.py", line 105, in get_python_version
    c = subprocess.Popen(version_cmd, **subprocess_kwargs)
  File "d:\python382\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "d:\python382\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\python382\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "d:\python382\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\python382\Scripts\pipenv.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "D:\python382\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\python382\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "D:\python382\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "D:\python382\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "D:\python382\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\python382\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\decorators.py", line 73, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\python382\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\python382\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\decorators.py", line 21, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\python382\lib\site-packages\pipenv\cli\command.py", line 232, in install
    retcode = do_install(
  File "d:\python382\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 1921, in do_install
    ensure_project(
  File "d:\python382\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 576, in ensure_project
    ensure_virtualenv(
  File "d:\python382\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 498, in ensure_virtualenv
    python = ensure_python(three=three, python=python)
  File "d:\python382\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 388, in ensure_python
    path_to_python = find_a_system_python(python)
  File "d:\python382\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 350, in find_a_system_python
    return next(iter(finder.find_all_python_versions()), None)
  File "d:\python382\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\pythonfinder.py", line 312, in find_all_python_versions
    python_version_dict = getattr(self.system_path, "python_version_dict", {})
  File "d:\python382\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\pythonfinder.py", line 120, in system_path
    self._system_path = self.create_system_path()
  File "d:\python382\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\pythonfinder.py", line 82, in create_system_path
    return pyfinder_path.SystemPath.create(
  File "D:\python382\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\path.py", line 682, in create
    instance = instance._run_setup()
  File "D:\python382\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\path.py", line 233, in _run_setup
    new_instance = new_instance._setup_windows()
  File "D:\python382\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\path.py", line 411, in _setup_windows
    windows_finder = WindowsFinder.create()
  File "D:\python382\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\windows.py", line 146, in create
    return cls()
  File "<attrs generated init pythonfinder.models.windows.WindowsFinder>", line 13, in __init__
  File "D:\python382\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\windows.py", line 113, in get_versions
    versions[py_version.version_tuple[:5]] = base_dir
  File "D:\python382\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\python.py", line 365, in __getattribute__
    result = super(PythonVersion, self).__getattribute__(key)
  File "D:\python382\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\python.py", line 430, in version_tuple
    self.patch,
  File "D:\python382\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\python.py", line 375, in __getattribute__
    instance_dict = self.parse_executable(executable)
  File "D:\python382\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\python.py", line 620, in parse_executable
    raise ValueError("Not a valid python path: %r" % path)
ValueError: Not a valid python path: 'D:/program_files/Anaconda3/Scripts/python.exe'
```

Running 'python -m pipenv.help' gives -

```
C:\Users\rd463>python -m pipenv.help
```

$ pipenv --support

Pipenv version: `'2020.6.2'`

Pipenv location: `'D:\\python382\\lib\\site-packages\\pipenv'`

Python location: `'D:\\python382\\python.exe'`

Python installations found:

followed by the same error again.

I have python installed in 'D:/python382'
There is no such directory that the error mentions. I have checked my environment variables and everything is fine there too. Please help me with this error.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 9):

I think the newer version of **pipenv** is causing the error, I use this command when having the same issue and it worked for me, just use

```
pip install pipenv==2018.10.13
```

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem when I uninstalled Anaconda. Mine got solved after I did the following steps

1. run regedit.exe
2. Go to

> Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python\PythonCore

3. If there is/are folders having previous versions of python.Delete every version of python other than your current one(for eg.3.7, 3.8 etc. I also had to delete some folder containing something related to anaconda to solve the problem (other than the previous versions)

Comment: In my case I uninstalled anaconda, but got these weird errors. removed the `3.8` in `\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python\PythonCore` where keys in `\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python\PythonCore\3.8\installPath` pointed toiwards the deleted `anaconda3` directory. And I also removed the `\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python\ContinuumAnalytics`. After restarting command prompt, pipenv worked fine again. Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 3):

I was just struggling with a similar problem with `pipenv` that was giving me the same error messages.

WinError 2 has to do with corrupted files in one of your Python installs/uninstalls. I searched regedit for Anaconda3 to figure out which version of Python that I had previously installed or uninstalled was causing the problem.

For me, it was Python 3.6.5. I installed it in the same location as the path in the error message (in your case that would be `D:/program_files/`). Then, I just uninstalled it with the installation exe, and I stopped getting these error messages.

Comment: TL;DR Similar solution worked for me but I just manually deleted the no-longer-valid registry keys.

I ran into a similar issue, but in my case a version of Anaconda that I (apparently) manually deleted from my user profile was still in the registry, and pipenv was picking that up. In my case I had all of the right keys under HKLM\SOFTWARE\Python\ContinuumAnalytics, but I had additional keys under *HKCU*\SOFTWARE\Python\ContinuumAnalytics that pointed to the old directory. Removing thenodes under  HKCU\...\ContinuumAnalytics allowed pipenv to get the right Python by default.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the conda install command? To do this, go on your anaconda prompt, cd in the folder where you have installed your anaconda. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26318995/installing-numpy-via-anaconda-in-windows).

`conda install -c conda-forge pipenv`

make sure you activate your environment before running the conda install command. To activate your environment run `conda activate envname`. I hope it helps!

Comment: I do not have anaconda installed. And I don't plan to. I just need pipenv to work with standard python for my work involving flask.